# Godot IDE debug display resolution change

Tags: godot

Please excuse the highly noob question.  Within the Godot IDE project settings, how do I decrease the size/resolution of the debug screen within the IDE without changing my project layout size?  My computer has a 1920 x 1080 resolution, the mobile resolution I am targeting is 720 x 1280.  This causes the bottom of the screen to appear out of sight when running a test.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, go to project settings and enter the display>window>size>width and height.

[image]